# How to set a background color to an element for specific time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: -20 + $('.clsname').offset().top});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="clsname">scroll to here</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

I also need to add this code to it:

```
var $el = $(".clsname"),
    x = 2000,
    originalColor = $el.css("background");

$el.css("background", "orange");
setTimeout(function(){
  $el.css("background", originalColor);
}, x);
```

I mean, I want to both scroll to an element and set it a orange background color for 2 sec. How can I do that?

**Note:** It would be perfect if the orange color **fade smoothly** after 2 sec.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some JS to change it based on whatever time, this being morning, day and night.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getHours();
    if (n > 19 || n < 6)
      // If time is after 7PM or before 6AM, apply night theme to ‘body’
      document.body.className = "night";
    else if (n > 16 && n < 19)
      // If time is between 4PM – 7PM sunset theme to ‘body’
      document.body.className = "sunset";
    else
      // Else use ‘day’ theme
      document.body.className = "day";
});
```

Comment: You are welcome to add a fade simply add transition: all 2s to your css style you have each color for

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `css animation` to switch `background-color`.

```js
$('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: -20 + $('.clsname').offset().top
});
```

```css
.clsname {
  background: none;
}
.clsname {
  -webkit-animation-name: example;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */

@-webkit-keyframes example {
  from {
    background: orange;
  }
  to {
    background:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="clsname">scroll to here</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: Just there is a small problem ... finally the background color will be orange .. well it shouldn't be, orange color should gone away after 2 sec. Something exactly like StackOverflow

Comment: Updated answer, check once.

Answer (score 1):

this will change the `background-color` after body scrolled below.

```js
 $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: -20 + $('.clsname').offset().top}, 2000);

setTimeout(function(){
   $('.clsname').css({backgroundColor: 'orange'});
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function(){
   $('.clsname').css({backgroundColor: 'transparent'});
}, 3000);
```

```css
.clsname{
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="clsname">scroll to here</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: The orange color should be hidden after  2sec forever. thank you anyway .. upvote

Answer (score 0):

Use a promise ,pass it a function to be run upon animation completion .You could also use success [callback](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) but promise is better as it avoids the problem of double callbacks due to `<html>` and `<body>` (added for browser compatibility)

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: -20 + $('.clsname').offset().top  }).promise().done(function(){
    var $el = $(".clsname"),
    x = 2000,
    originalColor = $el.css("background");
    $el.css("background", "orange");

    setTimeout(function(){
        $el.css("background", originalColor);
    }, x);
});
```